# How to replace some fields of an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

how can I replace all fields named "replaceMe" and "replaceMeToo" in an array? I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow, but no one helped me really.

$array is returned from $db->loadObjectList(); in Joomla.

Example var_dump of $array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#118 (14) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["replaceMe"]=>
    string(2) "48"
    ["replaceMeToo"]=>
    string(2) "53"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#119 (14) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["replaceMe"]=>
    string(2) "5555"
    ["replaceMeToo"]=>
    string(2) "5555"
  }
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
// @param int, @return string
$array['replaceMe'] = doSomething($array['replaceMe']);
$array['replaceMeToo'] = doSomething($array['replaceMeToo']);
```

The result should look like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#118 (14) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["replaceMe"]=>
    string(2) "I was replaced by a value from db #1"
    ["replaceMeToo"]=>
    string(2) "I was replaced by a value from db #2"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#119 (14) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["replaceMe"]=>
    string(2) "I was replaced by a value from db #3"
    ["replaceMeToo"]=>
    string(2) "I was replaced by a value from db #4"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me what do you want to get in result. Could you complete your question with result array you want to get after replacements?

Comment: Okay, I added an example for a result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach($array as $arr){

  $arr->replaceMeToo = $arr->replaceMe;
  unset($arr->replaceMe);

}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str_replace`, example code:

With loop:

```
foreach ($array as &$new) {
  $new = str_replace('replaceMe', 'replacedYou', str_replace('replaceMeToo', 'replacedYouTo', $new));
}
```

Without a loop:

```
$new = str_replace('replaceMe', 'replacedYou', str_replace('replaceMeToo', 'replacedYouTo', $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

Example

```
$yourArray = array("id","replaceMe","replaceMeToo");
$replaceMentArray = array(1 => "db1", 2 => "db2");
$newArray = array_replace($yourArray,$replaceMentArray);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => db1
    [2] => db2        
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers. You helped me! Everybody get a vote up.

I solved it so:

```
        $result = $db->loadObjectList();

        $newArray = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $tempArray = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'published' => $row->published,
                'date' => $row->date,
                'hours' => $row->hours,
                'class' => $row->class,
                'type' => $row->type,
                'subject' => $row->subject,
                'subject_sub' => $row->subject_sub,
                'teacher' => JFactory::getUser($row->teacher)->name, //replace userId with name
                'teacher_sub' => JFactory::getUser($row->teacher_sub)->name, // replace userId with name
                'room' => $row->room,
                'comment' => $row->comment,
                'created' => $row->created,
                'modified' => $row->modified
            );
            array_push($newArray, $tempArray);
        }

        echo json_encode($newArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```